# Need help with bitcoind " zapwallettxes " routine

Tags: bitcoind

It all started when I tried to make a couple of payments via bitcoin. The transactions just would not confirm. After doing some reading I saw that " zapwallettxes " would supposedly dump the transactions that would not confirm, so I could resend the payments. So I ran the routine.
    That was over 24 hours ago, and it's still running.  The only way I can tell it's still running is (a) I have a blinking cursor on the DOS screen, and (b) when I try to run my wallet it says it's currently busy. Has anyone has any experience with zapwallettxes ?  How long does it take to run?

Comment: What command did you actually run?

Comment: I ran -zapwallettxes

Comment: The full command, like `bitcoind -zapwallettxes`?

Comment: Bitcoin , yes I ran bitcoind -zapwallettxes  .  Is that OK or should there be something else?  Also how long should that take to run?

Comment: The daemon will keep running in the background when you do that, in another session run `bitcoin-cli stop` to safely shut it down. You should be alright on your next launch.